# Connect Symfony to a Sybase Database

Tags: php, symfony, sybase, sap-ase

Just before i get started, i have been trying to figure this out and have clicked nearly every google link there is and i have read nearly all the other questions on this nothing worked for me.

Is there any way to connect to an existant Sybase ase Database I've tried `sqlanywhere` , `sqlsrv` and `pdo_dblib` I always get  exceptions for example 
`Attempted to call function "sasql_connect" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLAnywhere".` when I use sqlanywhere

I'm using Symfony 2.8 php 5.5 on windows , Tried php 5.6 on ubuntu and it's the same

Thanks  for help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is low on specifics. Apparently you're connecting to Sybase SQLAnywhere? (and not Sybase ASE or Sybase IQ). Also, most other relevant details are missing.

Anyway, for SQL Anywhere, best use the SA JDBC 4.0 driver (sajdbc4.jar), rather than jConnect. For more info, see http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/choosing-jdbc-jdbc.html.

Comment: Those drivers are for Java not for PHP , I'm going to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case somebody comes here looking for the answer:

To connect to SQL Anywhere from Symfony/PHP, you need the SQL Anywhere module installed.  At the time of writing, it's unfortunately incompatible with PHP 8 and won't even compile.

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/The+SAP+SQL+Anywhere+PHP+Module